# How do I retrieve a process ID for the Win32 Windows Mobile platform?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, mfc, winapi

I would like to retrieve the process ID and handle of a process by querying for it by process name.  Is this possible to do on the Win32 Windows Mobile platform?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms939171.aspx), following with [Process32First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915359.aspx) and the related functions, following the general idea in the [code sample.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28VS.85%29.aspx)  The Process32... functions provide PROCESSENTRY32 for each process, which contains the Process ID.